# Pandas - concatenate nearest events from two dataframes with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help. I am stucked in a problem.

I have the following DF

DF1

```
DATETIME           ID       State

2020-07-29 00:15:10   A     Down
2020-07-29 00:25:10   B     Down
2020-07-29 01:14:30   A     Down
2020-07-29 02:15:50   A     Down
```

DF2

```
DATETIME            ID      State

2020-07-29 00:19:40   A     Up
2020-07-29 00:35:10   B     Up
2020-07-29 00:56:40   B     Up
2020-07-29 01:40:30   A     Up
2020-07-29 01:35:10   B     Up
2020-07-29 02:18:50   A     Up
2020-07-29 02:45:50   A     Up
```

I want the following result:

NEW DF

```
DATETIME             ID     State   Restore_DT
2020-07-29 00:15:10    A    Down    2020-07-29 00:19:40
2020-07-29 00:25:10    B    Down    2020-07-29 00:35:10
2020-07-29 01:14:30    A    Down    2020-07-29 01:40:30
2020-07-29 02:15:50    A    Down    2020-07-29 02:18:50
```

Theoretically, from DF1 I need to find the nearest event in DF2 that has the same ID.

What's the best approach for that?

Thank you

Comment: Use [`merge.asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='nearest'` parameter, also first sorting columns and created new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATETIME'])
df2['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATETIME'])

df1 = df1.sort_values('DATETIME')
df2 = df2.sort_values('DATETIME')

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2[['DATETIME','ID']].assign(Restore_DT = df2['DATETIME']), 
                   on='DATETIME', 
                   by='ID', 
                   direction='nearest')
print (df)
             DATETIME ID State          Restore_DT
0 2020-07-29 00:15:10  A  Down 2020-07-29 00:19:40
1 2020-07-29 00:25:10  B  Down 2020-07-29 00:35:10
2 2020-07-29 01:14:30  A  Down 2020-07-29 01:40:30
3 2020-07-29 02:15:50  A  Down 2020-07-29 02:18:50
```

Comment: just perfect! I dind't know this merger_asof. I am studing it now, but your code is just perfect. Thank you!!!

Comment: Just a quick update. Using direction nearest it was bringing dates before of df1. I changed to direction forward and solved the issue completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using `merge`.

First merge the df(this will merge datetime with the nearest datetime1)

```
df_cross_merge = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left').query('DATETIME <= DATETIME1')
```

And to get your desired df(keep only first datetime)

```
df_cross_merge =df_cross_merge.drop_duplicates(['DATETIME'],keep='first')
```

Comment: @jezrael It was just incomplete, I updated the answer and now the result it's ok. I tested but forgot to add the full answer. I am on the road and was eager to help :)

Comment: I tried to implement, but I a type error in the query. It says I can't compare date to type, but both columns (datetime and datetime1) are set to datetime using ```df2['datetime'] = df2['datetime'].astype('datetime64[ns]')````. Strange to receive this error....